# <div> with float right inner <li> element works only with one <li>. Why?

Tags: html, css

I have `<ul>` with bootstrap class and dynamically add `<li>` element with bootstrap class and clearfix

```
<ul class="list-group messages" id="messages">
</ul>


var li = $("<li></li>").addClass("list-group-item clearfix");
var div = $("<div></div>").addClass(align + "-align word").text(word);
div.appendTo(li);
$("#messages").prepend(li);
```

For example

[image]

Styles for `<li>`

```
.messages > li {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Styles for div inner `<li>`

```
.word {
    padding: 7px 37px;
    margin: 8px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

And I add class for div: r-align or l-align to align div inner `<li>` using float

```
.r-align {
    background-color: #c7eafc;
    color: #45829b;
    float: right;
}

.l-align {
    background-color: #ffe6cb;
    color: #c48843;
    float: left;
}
```

If I add li with l-align then r-align then l-align and so on then all ok.

[image]

But if I add two or more with same align, float don't works right. How to fix it? On image I have 3 div with r-align consequentially.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some man prompt me to experiment with margin or padding. And when I change padding on li to nonzero, float becomes work right.